# How to use the function move_uploaded_file creating some directory?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I'm going through some doubts about how do i need to set up my environment to be able to use this function correctly.

What i do really need is something like this:

I'm developing a classified website for my city, where each user has its id. When an user posts an ad, i have to take all the files he uploaded and move them to a new (or not new) directory.

The name of this directory is the user ID.

Does the function 'move_uploaded_file' create the directory if it does not exist?
If not, how could i do that?

Example:

```
//getUID() returns 5
//current directory: www/

move_uploaded_file('some_temp_file.ext','adimg/' . getUID() . '/new_file.ext');
```

Is it going to create the folder '5' and move the temporary file to it?

And how do i need to configure my folders (I'm testing it under Windows).

Thanks!

Comment: You can always programatically create the directory as long as your parent directory has the worldwide write access (777 in *nix, in Windows just tick those checkboxes to allow write access).

Comment: @AlvinWong Perfect. Now the thing is that i can't open the uploaded files, i don't know why i don't have permissions to do it. The files are uploaded, the folders is created but i can't open them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [php mkdir() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php). before using `move_uploade_file()` to create the directory(if you are creating the foler via php) where you want to put the files.

If you cant edit the folder persisson by checkboxes, you can set it via ftp client.

[image]